# black screen instead of camera in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I use OpenCV3.4.0 and I want to open camera implementing CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2. But it shows me black screen not a camera.

This is my code.

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    matInput = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    matInput.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    matInput = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(matInput, matInput, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    return matInput;
}
```

Comment: Have you granted Camera Permission to App ?

Comment: @ADM Yes, of course.

Comment: Have you tried running one of the many OpenCV apps that access the camera?

Comment: @Rick M. Yes, I did. It worked out the first few times, but at some point, a black screen appears.